# Using xpath.bat to extract values from XML file

Tags: xml, parsing, batch-file, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm currently trying to extract some values from an XML using batch and I have come across [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)

My XML file is formatted in the example below

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <data>
     <entry name="Bill" value="hello" type="string"/>
     <entry name="Bob" value="goodbye" type="string"/>
     <entry name="Fred" value="wait" type="string"/>
 <data>
```

I'd like to find a name in the XML file and report back the value associated. Using xpath.bat I've been able to list all the names but I am unable to retrieve the addtional values.

Alternatively, if anyone is able to extract these values and assign to atch variable using any other method i'd love to see it!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to find a name in the XML file and report back the value associated.

The shown XML does not have any element values, so it can't return any. It merely has attribute values. So the output seems to be correct.

If you instead want to return the `@value` attribute value (i.e. for "Bob") the XPath would have to look something like this:

```
/data/entry[name="Bob"]/@value
```